# Hypothesis testing with single subject design?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, modeling

I am trying to do a hypothesis testing on a problem like this.

We have a single patient, we have some data about his blood pressure before the treatment. We have some other data about his blood pressure after the treatment. The treatment is so special that we only have this patient.

I am hoping to prove that the treatment is useful to drop the blood pressure for this particular patient. I don't really care if the treatment is good for others.

Blood pressure is influenced by many factors, for our practical purpose, I am thinking about modeling those measurements as random samples from a population of all possible measurements for this patient.

So before the treatment, we measure it a few times, got a sample, and then after the treatment, we measure it a few times again, got another sample. I am hoping there is a technique such that I can tell if the drop in blood pressure is not due to randomness.

I know the data I have is not ideal, it is not independent samples, but that's all I have.

The blood pressure, treatment, patient are merely analogy of the situation. I cannot disclose the actual situation there, but the analogy is close enough to discuss this problem, just do not think too much about the actual problem domain and focus on the statistical techniques.

Comment: The question is a little vague.

Comment: Depending on what data you hafe, you may be able to do a statistical test to answer the question: Has this patient changed from before treatment to after treatment.  The answer to that question may not be all that relevant to this question: Does the treatment in question help patients in general.  Since you seem to have no idea what statistical test to run, you might best consult with a statistician rather than rely on the limited advice you might get here.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I agree the question is vague. I am in the process of formulating the problem, taking into consideration of whether or not there is a solution or not.

Comment: Thanks Joel. It makes a lot of sense to conclude that with only the data of one patient, we cannot reasonably argue the behavior of the treatment on any other patient. What if my problem is simply to test whether the treatment is good for that particular patient? What technique is good for the purpose?

Comment: Cross-over (if it is not a fast-progressing disease and a non-disease-modifying treatment): treat them same patient a few times with the intervention and also a control intervention (e.g. placebo) in a random sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the comments. They make me think much more. To do hypothesis testing, I need population, sampling, randomness. 

I make an edit to the post to allow those factors to appear. Does my problem more concrete/make sense now?